# How to click a button On Yahoo Finance using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, webdriverwait

I was trying automatically pull "quarterly" data from the financial reports found on yahoo finance and could not find a way to do it. I thought I could click "the quarterly button" from the financial page (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL) but below code didn't work. (Nothing happen) Would you please correct the code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
ticker_list = ["AAPL"]

for ticker in ticker_list:

    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + ticker + "/financials?p=" + ticker
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3600)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Quarterly"]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Quarterly"]').click
```

Comment: on the last link, call the click function `diver.find_element_by_xpath('foo').click()`

Answer (score 1):

The "Quarterly" text is part of a `span` tag within the button element, so isn't found. If you change your XPath to `//span[text()="Quarterly"]` instead then that works for me

Comment: wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Quarterly"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Quarterly"]').click
I don't know why but it still does not work for me...

Comment: Do you also need to call `.click()` instead of `.click`?

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as **Quarterly** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  ticker_list = ["AAPL"]
  for ticker in ticker_list:
      url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/financials?p={}".format(ticker, ticker)
      driver.get(url)
      WebDriverWait(driver, 3600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@data-test='qsp-financial']//span[text()='Quarterly']"))).click()
  ```